# Java Swing change UI twice in the actionPerformed function while waiting for a method

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, awt, jtextfield

simple problem explanation: When a button is pushed in my UI it calls on a different class to run some logic. This logic, by design, takes about a minute. I want to update a JTextField before I call the function to say "Please Wait blah blah" and then update that text after the function completes. What I'm seeing is that the UI doesn't refresh until exiting the actionPerformed function, so nothing happens until the text is updated to "Complete"

Sample below:

```
JTextField warn = new JTextField("Press submit to begin");//This is a member var
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
        Object source = ev.getSource();

        if(source == submitButton) {
            warn.setText("Please wait 60 seconds");
            Display.doThingThatTakesAMinute();
            warn.setText("Complete");
        }
    }
```

Per the description above, when the button is pressed it stays pressed for 60 seconds, displaying the original "Press submit to begin" until it says "Complete". Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SwingWorker` to run a long process off the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).
Using a `SwingWorker`prevents the GUI from freezing, and allows you to show interim as well as final results of the long process:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingWorkerWaitDemo {

    public static void creategui(){

        JFrame f = new JFrame("SwingWorker Demo");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new MainPanel());
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        creategui();
    }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    private MyWorker swingWorker;
    private final JLabel interimResults;
    private final JButton submit, cancel;
    private final JTextField warn;

    MainPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(2, 2));
        submit = new JButton("Submit");
        submit.addActionListener(e->start());
        cancel = new JButton("Stop");
        cancel.setEnabled(false);
        cancel.addActionListener(e->cancel());
        JPanel ssPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        ssPane.add(submit); ssPane.add(cancel);
        add(ssPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        interimResults = new JLabel();
        JPanel outputPane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        outputPane.add(interimResults);
        add(outputPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

         warn = new JTextField("Press Submit to begin");
        JPanel responsePane = new JPanel();
        responsePane.add(warn);
        add(responsePane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(400, 100);
    }

    private void start() {
        submit.setEnabled(false);
        cancel.setEnabled(true);
        swingWorker = new MyWorker();
        swingWorker.execute();
        warn.setText("Long process is running. Press Cancel to stop.");
    }

    private void cancel() {
        cancel.setEnabled(false);
        swingWorker.setStop(true);
    }

    class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

        private boolean stop = false;

        @Override
        //long processing done in background
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {

            int counter = 0;

            while(! stop && counter < 60){
                publish(counter++);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            return counter;
        }

        @Override
        //show interim results
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
            for (int i : chunks) {
                interimResults.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        //invoked when swingworker has finished
        protected void done() {
            warn.setText(stop ? "Process stopped": "All done");
            cancel.setEnabled(false);
        }

        void setStop(boolean stop) {
            this.stop = stop;
        }
    }
}
```